# How to create an animated plot over the top of an image - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animated-gif

I am doing some work with a client where I would like to show a plot/route which is taken by an employee. I would like this to be animated based on a specific order so that I can demonstrate how many times the employee goes back to a trolley.

I've managed to read the image and plot the anchor points on the image. I'm just a bit lost on how to get the plot line to animate between the points.

[CAD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSbzR.jpg)

```
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# to read the image stored in the working directory
data = image.imread('Asset 1.png') 

# to draw points on co-ordinates
plots = np.array([[500,200], #trolley
                  [420,200], #bath/shower
                  [370,45],  #wardrobe
                  [370,320], #sink
                  [320,250], #toilet
                  [280,45],  #fridge/coffee
                  [175,40],  #desk
                  [180,150], #bed
                  [250,220], #bedside table 1
                  [110,220], #bedside table 2
                  [40,150],  #table
                  [20,100], #window/curtains
                  [65,190], #chair
                  [75,75]]) #carpet 

x,y = plots.T fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(data)
plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', color="red") 
fig.savefig('DoubleRoom.png')
plt.show()
```

This gets me the above image. But how do I plot between the points?
e.g. Step 1 = trolley -> bath/shower
Step 2 = shower -> bed etc.

Hopefully the request makes sense and any help or guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a possible way to do this. I used the picture you shared as the background of the animation. You can then initiate your plot with `plt.imshow(data)` and `l,=plt.plot(plots[0,0],plots[0,1],marker='o',ls='--',lw=2,markersize=10)` and change the values of the plot at each frame with `set_xdata` and `set_ydata` in the update function. Note that there is a slight offset in the trajectory because I don't have access to the original picture of the room.

```py
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
# to read the image stored in the working directory
data = image.imread('asset.jpg') 

# to draw points on co-ordinates
plots = np.array([[500,200], #trolley
                  [420,200], #bath/shower
                  [370,45],  #wardrobe
                  [370,320], #sink
                  [320,250], #toilet
                  [280,45],  #fridge/coffee
                  [175,40],  #desk
                  [180,150], #bed
                  [250,220], #bedside table 1
                  [110,220], #bedside table 2
                  [40,150],  #table
                  [20,100], #window/curtains
                  [65,190], #chair
                  [75,75]]) #.Tcarpet 

#Set up of the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(data) # set background of animation
l,=plt.plot(plots[0,0],plots[0,1],marker='o',ls='--',lw=2,markersize=10) 

#remove box and axes around plot
plt.box(False)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

def update(i): #update value of plot
  l.set_xdata(plots[:i+1,0])
  l.set_ydata(plots[:i+1,1])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=plots.shape[0]) #animate
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect to what I need to achieve, thanks! Can you just explain this part - how is it using this code to plot the values. So if i want to pass the values of x and y from arrays for example - how would they form in this block of code?

```def update(i): #update value of plot
  l.set_xdata(plots[:i+1,0])
  l.set_ydata(plots[:i+1,1])
```

Comment: Sure, the two functions `set_xdata` and `set_ydata` are updating the x and y values of your plot at a specific frame. Here, `plots[:i+1,0]` is the first column of your array `plots` up to index `i`. And same thing for `plots[:i+1,1]` being the second column of your array up to `i` for y

Comment: That makes sense having walked through the code. The trouble is, i'm running the code (with the original image) and it's not iterating and only plotting the first point.

Comment: Sorry @jylls what am I missing - the code snippet doesn't iterate and only plots the first point which I'm guessing is
`l,=plt.plot(plots[0,0],plots[0,1],marker='o',ls='--',lw=2,markersize=10)`
but the l doesn't update in the update function? I've tried returning l but that doesn't work either?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the issue? Are you using google colab by any chance? Regardless of the platform try using the line `ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=3)` after you run the code and open the gif file to check if you see the animation.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter Notebook and have also added in the last line that you reference above. Basically, it is only plotting the first point and doesn't move on to plot the next x,y coordinate in the array. This leaves it just with one marker on the image.

Answer (score 0):

To animate, you need to use animation from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

```
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(plots), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So in this instance @abdulmajeed if fig is my CAD image, animate is the coordinates array and order in which to pass the animation, frames = number of plots?